# how to embed a Tkinter progressbar in a function in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I wish to understand how to embed a progessbar of Tkinter in a function (ex: foo) with an easy example. I wrote this code where the first button is a indeterminate progessbar, the second is a determinate progessbar, and the third button the function where i try to insert the progessbar. I tried with a error message to insert `self.pbar_ind.step(1)` and `self.update()` inside `foo`

```
**res = foo(self, 5)
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined**
```

.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
import time

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("ProgressBar example")
        self.master.minsize(200, 100)
        self.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.start_ind = Button(self, text='Start indeterminate', command=self.start_ind, activeforeground="red")
        self.start_ind.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.pbar_ind = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="indeterminate")
        self.pbar_ind.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.start_det = Button(self, text='Start determinate', command=self.start_det, activeforeground="red")
        self.start_det.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.pbar_det = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
        self.pbar_det.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.inside_f = Button(self, text='Start function', command=self.start_fun, activeforeground="red")
        self.inside_f.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.pbar_f = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
        self.pbar_f.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

    def foo(self, m):
        for i in xrange(m):
            i * 2
            self.pbar_det.step(1)
            self.update()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        return i


    def start_ind(self):
        for i in xrange(500):
            self.pbar_ind.step(1)
            self.update()
            # Busy-wait
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def start_det(self):
        for i in xrange(500):
            self.pbar_det.step(1)
            self.update()
            # Busy-wait
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def start_fun(self):
        res = foo(500)


if __name__=="__main__":
   d = MainWindow()
   d.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the (full) error message ?

Comment: Why `foo()` is outside class ?

Comment: Hi Furas, I cannot write self.pbar_ind.step(1) and self.update() outside the class

Comment: So why `foo() ` is outside class - it should be part of class.

Comment: is it possible to use foo() outside the class?

Comment: You can use `self` outside the class directly - but maybe you could send `self` as  argument `fun(500, self) `

Comment: if i insert foo inside the class foo(self, m) i got this error message NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined

Comment: @furas see the new edit

Comment: Inside class you have to call it as `self.foo(500)`

Comment: Thanks @furas, do you think is possible to take out the class foo?

Comment: Yes, If you need it - but I prefer to use class - code is cleaner and easer to find something.

Comment: I add version without class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things

1) add `foo()` to class:

```
def start_fun(self):
    res = self.foo(500) # use self.

def foo(self, m):
    for i in xrange(m):
        i * 2
        self.pbar_det.step(1)
        self.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return i
```

2) send `self` to external `foo()`

```
def foo(m, self_from_class):
    for i in xrange(m):
        i * 2
        self_from_class.pbar_det.step(1)
        self_from_class.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return i

class MainWindow(Frame):

    # ...

    def start_fun(self):
        res = foo(500, self)
```

---

BTW:

everything without class

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def foo(m):
    for i in xrange(m):
        i * 2
        pbar_f.step(1)
        master.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return i

def start_ind():
    for i in xrange(500):
        pbar_ind.step(1)
        master.update()
        # Busy-wait
        time.sleep(0.1)

def start_det():
    for i in xrange(500):
        pbar_det.step(1)
        master.update()
        # Busy-wait
        time.sleep(0.1)

def start_fun(self):
    res = foo(500)
    print 'res:', res

master = Tk()

master.title("ProgressBar example")
master.minsize(200, 100)
#grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

#top = winfo_toplevel()
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

start_ind = Button(master, text='Start indeterminate', command=start_ind, activeforeground="red")
start_ind.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

pbar_ind = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="indeterminate")
pbar_ind.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

start_det = Button(master, text='Start determinate', command=start_det, activeforeground="red")
start_det.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

pbar_det = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
pbar_det.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

inside_f = Button(master, text='Start function', command=start_fun, activeforeground="red")
inside_f.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

pbar_f = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
pbar_f.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

master.mainloop()
```